# Frequency capped sum in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, groovy

In Elasticsearch, I have indexed documents of the form:

```
{
  "device_id": "abc",
  "views": 123,
  + other criteria
}
```

I can compute:

- The count of unique devices using a [`cardinality aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-cardinality-aggregation.html) on `device_id`
- The overall number of views using a [`sum aggregation`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-metrics-sum-aggregation.html) on `views`

**How can I compute the sum of the views such that a given device can only account for a maximum of `n` views?**

For example, if my docs are:

```
{"device_id": "a", "views": 3, ...}
{"device_id": "a", "views": 4, ...}
{"device_id": "a", "views": 1, ...}
{"device_id": "b", "views": 2, ...}
{"device_id": "c", "views": 6, ...}
```

And my `n` is `5`, then the result should be `12` = (5 for `a` even though its total is 8 + 2 for `b` + 5 for `c`)

My indices contain ~500,000 distinct devices.

The result does not need to be exact and can be approximate within *reasonable bounds*.

I do not mind using my own script using a combinations of techniques (HLL, Count-Min Sketch, Bloomfilters, Min Hash, ...)